# Quick question on partial derivative of a gradient vector field,

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Given a scalar field $x_1(u,v,w,t)$ that maps $R^4$ to $R$,

Do I have this correct:

$$\frac {\partial}{\partial t} \nabla x_1$$
$$=\frac {\partial}{\partial t}(\frac {\partial x_1}{\partial u},\frac {\partial x_1}{\partial v},\frac {\partial x_1}{\partial w},\frac {\partial x_1}{\partial t}) $$
$$=(\frac {\partial}{\partial t}\frac {\partial x_1}{\partial u},\frac {\partial}{\partial t}\frac {\partial x_1}{\partial v},\frac {\partial}{\partial t}\frac {\partial x_1}{\partial w},\frac {\partial}{\partial t}\frac {\partial x_1}{\partial t})? $$

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do have this correct.

You can precede parentheses (or any pair of delimiters) by `\left` and `\right` to make the parentheses adjust to the size of their content.

Comment: Hi @joriki - ok, got it.  Thanks so much for the confirmation and also for the nice formatting tip; I'll remember to use it going forward.  Have a great night :-)